# How to get declared type with mirrors?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';


void main() {
  var mirror = reflectClass(MyClass);
  mirror.declarations.forEach((k, v){
    print(k);
    if(v is VariableMirror){
      print(v.type);
    }
  });
}


class MyClass{
  var aDynamic;
  int anInt;
}

//prints:
Symbol("aDynamic")
TypeMirror on 'dynamic'
Symbol("anInt")
ClassMirror on 'int'
Symbol("MyClass")
```

is there a way I can get the Type the TypeMirror is refelcting so Id like to return a type of `dynamic` and of type `int` for the 2 properties in the example above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VariableMirror.type` is the right way to go. If it returns a ClassMirror, then you can use `ClassMirror.reflectedType` to get the Type object for the declaration.

`VariableMirror.type` will be the *declared* type of the variable, not the type of any value the variable holds, so while it will be a TypeMirror it might not be a ClassMirror. It could also be a TypeVariableMirror or TypedefMirror. You can see in your output that the mirror for the dynamic case is a TypeMirror on `dynamic`. So you have to figure out how to deal with those. For instance, there is no Type object that represents `dynamic`, so you have to handle that separately. I would probably just convert it to `Object`. For TypedefMirrors, you could return `Function`. I'm not actually sure what other TypeMirrors that aren't a subtype there might be.

Here's some example code:

```dart
final _dynamicType = reflectType(dynamic);

Type getDeclaredType(VariableMirror m) {
  var t = m.type;
  if (t is ClassMirror) return t.reflectedType;
  if (t is TypedefMirror) return Function;
  if (t == _dynamicType) return Object;
  throw new ArgumentError("I don't know how to handle ${t}");
}
```